# Mercurial on linux or windows server

Tags: mercurial

I have the choice between Centos and windows server 2008 to deploy as a mercurial server.

I am pretty confident with both operating systems, although probably a little more with windows.

For this question assume I am equally confident with both Operating systems.

Which should I use with regard to ease of maintenance, stability and backups?

Or is there just no difference?

Comment: Hesitating for the close reason between Off Topic, Subjective and Argumentative, Belongs to ServerFault or Not a real question.

Comment: I'll try to make this better! It is a genuine question I am finding hard to answer at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one you're most comfortable with.

There's no point in installing CentOS / Windows if you've never used it and lose hours on configuration and other problems.

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer the linux server. But you could use [SCM-Manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager), then it is very easy on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Four of your last five answers have been you suggesting SCM-Manager, which you wrote.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that, of course, but it really smacks of boosterism.

Comment: Don't know about other 4 questions, but for this one the given answer is definitely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with CentOS simply to avoid the licensing fee. Plus it's just as easy to setup and configure as a Windows server if you know what you are doing.